# Using Volley, i make a StringRequest, and get Response, How to use <select> Tag (DropDown) Key-Value?

Tags: android

Using Volley, I make a StringRequest and getting String object as response. like,

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response);  // response is HTML

Element e = doc.getElementById("contact_type");

String  option = e.text(); // output is :  Select Self CA ERI TRP Others

String  html = e.html();  // <select tag > given below

String option_value = e.val(); // not working

}
```

Output of [ String  html = e.html(); ]

```
<select id="contact_type" style="width: 150px"  onblur="validateField_userContactDetails_SecContactType(this,true)" name="userContactDetails.SecContactType">
<option value="-1"> Select </option>
<option value="1">Self</option>
<option value="2">CA</option>
<option value="3">ERI</option>
<option value="4">TRP</option>
<option value="5">Others</option>
</select>
```

Above i use Document to parse HTML response.

Since Volley returns parse and structured data. So How to get Dropdown menu Key-Value pair data, which is coming with response.

Is any way using Volley functionality to extract  tag data directly into HashMap .

Because I want to populate my Spinner UI with the above Key-Value pair data .

Answer (score 0):

first make two Array references only, (like String[] contact_type_key,contact_type_value)

```
try {
Elements e = doc.select("select[id=contact_type] > option");
// initializing the array
contact_type_key = new String[e.size()];
contact_type_value = new String[e.size()];
// getting data into array
for (Element data : e) {
contact_type_key[e.indexOf(data)] = data.ownText();
contact_type_value[e.indexOf(data)] = data.attr("value");
}
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

than use key array with Spinner and get the value array[index] onItemSelected...